# Login page is stuck in redirection loop after using omniauth . While it was working fine before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I am working on a site that has two sides one for user and second for admin. I have used devise gem for authentication. Every thing was working fine but suddenly when I sign in to my admin account. The page is not working. I have recently worked on omniauth gem but I have not touched any previous code. I have tried to check the current_user but it is "nil". I think it is not getting user data in the application controller. Here is my code.

Application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  add_flash_types :success, :warning, :danger, :info
  protect_from_forgery prepend: true
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  layout :layout_by_resource

 def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

  def logged_in_using_omniauth
    session[:logged_in_using_omniauth].present?
  end
  helper_method :logged_in_using_omniauth

  private

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      "admin"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end

  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if(resource.admin==false)
      '/donations/donor_history'
    else
      '/admins/create_account' #your path
    end
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    '/users/sign_in' #your path
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit(:admin, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:first_name,:last_name)
    end
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit(:admin, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:current_password,:first_name,:last_name)
    end
  end

end
```

The admin controller is

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_admin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :social_media_sharing]
    before_action :check_admin_level, only: [:donation_analysis]
    helper_method :resource_name, :resource, :devise_mapping
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    before_filter do
        redirect_to new_user_session_path unless current_user && current_user.admin?
    end
    before_filter :index

    COMMON_YEAR_DAYS_IN_MONTH = [nil, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

    layout "admin"
    # GET /admins
    # GET /admins.json
    def resource_name
        :admin
    end

    def resource
        @resource ||= User.new
    end

    def devise_mapping
        @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:admin]
    end
    -----------
```

user model is

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable,
    :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook,:twitter,:linkedin]
  has_many :organizations_users
  has_many :organizations, through: :organizations_users

    def active_for_authentication?
    # Uncomment the below debug statement to view the properties of the returned self model values.
    super && self.active && self.exp_alert == false
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user =  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.active = 'true'
      user.admin=='false'
      user.exp_alert == 'false'
      user.skip_confirmation!
    end
    user
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end

  def self.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
    user = where(provider: auth_hash.provider, uid: auth_hash.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.first_name =  auth_hash.info.nickname
      user.active = 'true'
      user.admin=='false'
      user.exp_alert == 'false'
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.token =  auth_hash.credentials.token
      user.email =  "#{auth_hash.info.nickname}@test.com"
      user.secret =  auth_hash.credentials.secret
      user.skip_confirmation!
    end
    user
  end

  def self.linkedin_hash(auth_hash)
    user = where(provider: auth_hash.provider, uid: auth_hash.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.first_name =  auth_hash.info.first_name
      user.last_name =  auth_hash.info.last_name
      user.active = 'true'
      user.admin=='false'
      user.exp_alert == 'false'
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.token =  auth_hash.credentials.token
      user.email =  auth_hash.info.email
      user.skip_confirmation!
    end
    user
  end

  def inactive_message
    "Your Account has not been active yet."
  end

  def after_confirmation
    super
    self.update_attribute(:active, true)
  end
end
```

routes are

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users,  controllers: {confirmations: 'confirmations',registrations: 'users/registrations',omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' } do
    get "confirmation", to: "confirmations#after_confirmation_path_for"
     delete 'sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end

  devise_for :models

  get 'donations/donor_history/' => 'donations#donor_history'
  get 'donations/donor_signup/' => 'donations#donor_signup'
  post 'donations/donor_signup/' => 'donations#donor_signup'
  post 'donations/sms_service/' => 'donations#sms_service'
  post 'donations/create_user_account' => 'donations#create_user_account'
  post 'donations/add_user_payroll' => 'donations#add_user_payroll'

  resources :donations, except: [:new, :create]

  resources :campaigns do
    resources :donations, only: [:new, :create, :create_user_account]
    get 'donations/create_user_account' => 'donations#create_user_account'
  end
  resources :organizations

  post 'admins/social_sharing_switch/' => 'admins#social_sharing_switch'
  get 'admins/error_detail/' => 'admins#error_detail'
  get 'admins/generate_report/:id' => 'admins#generate_report'
  get 'admins/create_company/' => 'admins#create_company'
  post 'admins/create_company/' => 'admins#create_company'
  get 'admins/revenue_detail/' => 'admins#revenue_detail'
  get 'admins/create_account' => 'admins#create_account'
  get 'admins/view_account' => 'admins#view_account'
  get 'admins/view_company/:id' => 'admins#view_company'
  constraints RouteConstraint.new do
    get 'admins/donation_analysis' => 'admins#donation_analysis'
  end

  get 'admins/link_expiry' => 'admins#link_expiry'
  get 'admins/edit_profile' => 'admins#edit_profile'
  post 'admins/update_profile' => 'admins#update_profile'
  match '/admins/create_account', to: 'admins#create_account', via: 'post'
  match '/admins/:id', to: 'admins#destroy', via: 'get' , as: 'admin_destroy'

  resources :admins

  get 'crons/expirylink_alert' => 'crons#expirylink_alert'


  devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end


  root to: "campaigns#latest"
end
```

Logs are

```
Started GET "/admins/create_account" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:38 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AdminsController#create_account as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x00000002223c68@/vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:6> rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:38 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/admins/create_account
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started GET "/admins/create_account" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:38 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AdminsController#create_account as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x00000002223c68@/vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:6> rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/admins/create_account
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/admins/create_account" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AdminsController#create_account as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x00000002223c68@/vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:6> rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/admins/create_account
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started GET "/admins/create_account" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AdminsController#create_account as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x00000002223c68@/vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:6> rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/admins/create_account
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


Started GET "/admins/create_account" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AdminsController#create_account as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x00000002223c68@/vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:6> rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/admins/create_account
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/admins/create_account" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AdminsController#create_account as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x00000002223c68@/vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:6> rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/admins/create_account
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/admins/create_account" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AdminsController#create_account as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x00000002223c68@/vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:6> rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/admins/create_account
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


Started GET "/admins/create_account" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:40 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AdminsController#create_account as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x00000002223c68@/vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:6> rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:40 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/admins/create_account
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


Started GET "/admins/create_account" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:40 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AdminsController#create_account as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x00000002223c68@/vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:6> rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:40 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/admins/create_account
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)


Started GET "/admins/create_account" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:40 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AdminsController#create_account as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x00000002223c68@/vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:6> rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:40 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/admins/create_account
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started GET "/admins/create_account" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-12-02 15:13:40 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AdminsController#create_account as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 64810987], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x00000002223c68@/vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:6> rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it my self and now I am sharing this Answer so that it may help anyone else in the future.

The problem was the current_user variable which was overriding in the application controller.

```
def current_user
 @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

Devise set the current_user variable itself and this code was overriding the current_user variable. The strange thing is that the same code was working before without any problem. I think devise has updated.
However after comment the above code every thing is working fine.